# Interfaz en terminal python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estimados usuarios de la comunidad, quisiera saber si en **Windows** utilizando **Python 3.x** es posible crear y/o ejecutar un programa desde la terminal como se haría usualmente en sistemas como Linux. Dejo una imagen como ejemplo.
Aclaro también que la imagen no es de mi autoría y recalco que es solo como un referente a lo que intento hacer en **Windows
[image: Quisiera hacer algo así en Windows]

Aclaro también que es netamente un ejemplo de **INTERFAZ** pues lo que yo intento hacer es un programa educativo para aprender idiomas a extranjeros

Comment: algun aporte a mi pregunta? @SergioRamos

Comment: empieza por las opciones y para los colores https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors podrias simplemente un print "texto1" + "\n" etc..

Comment: Respuesta breve: sí puede hacerse, pero necesitarás instalar módulos de terceros. Uno que parece hacer lo que quieres y que funciona tanto en linux como en Windows es [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente puedes crear aplicaciones/scripts desde la terminal de Windows con Python. Para ejecutar un programa desde la terminal de Windows debes poner: **python *nombre_de_tu_programa***

Acuérdate en la instalación de python de marcar la casilla de python como variable del sistema para que pueda reconocer el comando python en la terminal.

Por otro lado, te aconsejaría que si realmente vas a crear una aplicación (y no un script) que utilizases alguna librería como ***tkinter*** o ***pyqt*** para realizar una aplicación de escritorio. Existen más, pero yo te recomendaría la primera. Si no las conoces busca en internet o youtube donde puedes encontrar información.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero lo unico que obtengo al hacer lo que me indicas es " Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Programa.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Proyecto.Programa import funciones
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Proyecto'"

Comment: Por lo demas.... muchas gracias por tu ayuda Juan

Comment: Parece claro que tienes un problema con que no encuentra el módulo "Proyecto". Mira la ruta en la que tienes Proyecto ya que seguramente no esté al mismo nivel que tu "programa.py".